# Unable to map when file is not existed in file downloading in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I am developing a web application using struts2 .. In that I am downloding a file when user clicks a link .. 
  When user clicks the link I am checking in my action class whether requested file is existed or not if it is existed then it is working fine ... 
  WHen it is not existed I am giving a action error message .. But That page is redirecting to error page that i have mapped globally .. IN my console ther is no exception message except these error lines .. 
 `Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [fileInputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.` 
 And I can see that action message in my error page ... I have debugged the problem also .. Mapping also perfect ..

```
<action name="downloadAction" class="DownloadPDFAction" method="pdfDownload" >
      <result name="success" type="stream">              
          <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
          <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
          <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${downloadDoc}".pdf</param>
          <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
       </result>
```

Is It possible to map back to the same JSP when The file is not existed in SYSTEM .. Thanks

Comment: Show your action configuration.

Comment: I have edited my question with my Action configuration .. THnak yoou

Comment: So define `error` result for action and return it in your action class.

Comment: The JSP which and the data on that page generated by Seperate action . So When I map result as `error` to the same page I am losing the previous data ... For that I have tried action type `redirect` But its not giving the exactt previous postition.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the file exists or not in the action, and return `success` & `error` respectively. You can do something like this :

> ```
> <action name="downloadAction" class="DownloadPDFAction" method="pdfDownload" >
>       <result name="success" type="stream">              
>           <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
>           <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
>           <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${downloadDoc}".pdf</param>
>           <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
>        </result>
> <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
> ```

**error.jsp**

```
<s:actionerror/>
<s:actionmessage/>
or your hard-coded message
```

But since, you need to go back to the same page, then I suggest calling the download action using ajax and return 200 on success and 204 on error something like this :

```
<action name="downloadAction" class="DownloadPDFAction" method="pdfDownload" >
          <result name="success" type="stream">              
              <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
              <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
              <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${downloadDoc}".pdf</param>
              <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
           </result>
    <result name="error" type="httpheader">
         <param name="status">204</param>
    </result>
```

The ajax call can be something like - [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    },
    204: function() {
      alert( "file not found" );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Its working fine.... But I couldnt get the alert box .. ? is it  `statusCode` and `param` name `status` has to be same or different ... if it has to be same In that case I have tried like that also but didnt work .. Dont know what happened .. Thank you

Comment: check the request being & response received using chrome-developer-tools.

Comment: I have tried using FireBug but didnt find .. And I am sorry I dont have that much access at my Work place to download all these .. Thank you ...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI - Learn to use the network tab for the request being sent and response being received.