# Unable to map the Ajax response in struts2

Tags: javascript, ajax, struts2

I am trying to get the ajax response a status code to print a dialogue box. I have taken reference from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806223/unable-to-map-when-file-is-not-existed-in-file-downloading-in-struts-2). Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    statusCode: {
        155: function () {
            alert("This Book is already exist please reject the request."); 
        }       
    }
});
```

My struts.xml

```
<action name="some action" class="some class" method="some method">
   <result name="gotcha" type="httpheader" >
       <param name="status"  >155 </param> 
   </result>
```

Here is my problem. when I try to run this on `IE` its redirecting to "The page cannot be displayed"

And When I tried in Firefox, the browser redirects the same page but the alert box does not show. I am unable to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess 155 is not defined, although all 1xx series is meant to for informational, but 155 is not defined.

Try changing it with 200, 201 etc.

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: why not try changing & executing